# Android Compose preview "Render problem" with API 34 and Compose UI 1.5.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I recently started a new app using Compose. I have AS Hedgehog  2023.1.1 installed. I am using API 34 and get an error in the compose preview. "Render problem" accompanied by a

```
Layout fidelity warning

The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate: 
    - The current rendering only supports APIs up to 33. You may encounter crashes if using with higher APIs. To avoid, you can set a lower API for your preview.
```

How do I set a lower API for previews?

Googling I only find results telling me to drop the API level of the entire app, OR answers from 2 years ago pointing to using a very old version of compose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use @Preview(apiLevel = 33), like below

```
@Preview(apiLevel = 33)
@Composable
fun YourComposablePreview() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue arises because the IDE doesn't yet support API 34. While @Kai's answer is effective, I find it better to **simply ignore the warning**.

This error will disappear on its own with an IDE update, and there's no risk of accidentally limiting your preview to an older API version later.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a dropdown above the preview window allowing to select different API versions for preview. Selecting 33 or below from the list makes the warning go away.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading in most cases.

Check Build > "Render Problem" for getting exact underlying issue.

I was printing logs and logging them to Firebase, so for preview Firebase Initialisation was required. Removing that dependency resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the preview window had a very low scale. Pressing the plus button several times showed the composable elements with Preview annotation